# Why Clustered Index Speeds up Select Top

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table

```
id, name, date
```

It has 300 million rows.

When I run:

```
select top 100000 * from table
```

it takes upwards of 30 seconds to run (SQL Server 2016 latest sp / su 24 cores and 148GB Ram, all flash raid)

I add a clustered index on `id`, run the same query and it returns almost immediately.

Why is it faster with the PK? Why wouldn't SQL Server just grab the top N rows off the data file and return them in the absence of the index?

This makes me think its doing some kind or sorting, but I cant tell what it would be using.

More on this to answer some of the questions.

The application here is our archiver that basically does this (pseudo code)

```
while @@rowcount <> 0
    insert into z.archive
        select from (delete top 100000 from dbo.maintable output deleted.*)
CHECKPOINT
```

There is a very significant improvement in speed associated with having the index.

I don't have both plans handy, but before the index it was indeed a table scan. But why is that slower than the index? Given the lack of a predicate I don't understand why it isn't just grabbing the first N records from the data file and sending them back

Comment: check out the execution plan to see what's really going on

Comment: If you did these runs back to back, the the second time, the 100 k rows are likely all in cache. no disk i/o

Comment: The execution plan will probably reveal that information,

Comment: can you [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)? If this was a single column table it would result in a table scan, and an index scan but the other columns matter here a lot too.

Comment: I'm curious if you drop the clustered index, does the time go back to 30 seconds.

Comment: `Top` without `order by` is supposed to return which rows?

Comment: That **IS** the difference between a table with a proper clustered key, and a heap (a "steaming pile" of data - without any clustering key) ....

Answer (score 0):

In a 300 million row table, I am assuming that you obviously are having a lot of fragmentation in the table.

Creating a clustered index would remove the fragmentation, reduce the number of pages to be read and sorted it so that the query optimizer could perform a seek instead of a scan on the table. The difference would be the amount of reads that SQL Server needs to do to return the number of rows asked for

Comment: Seek on the index perhaps? I’d still expect a index scan here though.